# Apply CSS class to element based on a keyword in the URL with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an URL like this:

http://mysite.com/something/view/something-else/

I want to hide all the images with the class `.attachment` inside all the pages that have the `/view/` part in the URL using jQuery.

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like this

```
var url = window.location.pathname;

if(url.indexOf('/view/') >= 0){
    $('.attachment').css('display','none');
}
```

Here is an example... you need to click Run to see it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/rAkGS/

Comment: I think you want `url.indexOf('/view/') >= 0` since `'/view/'` can be at the beginning of the pathname so `indexOf()` could find it and return `0`.

Comment: or `url.indexOf('/view/') != -1`

Comment: I guess I could have used `url.indexOf('/view/') != -1` as well.