# Apply a class to a <h1> based on the site url

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to PHP and want to apply a specific class to the title  of my page depending on what part of the site the viewer is browsing.

For instance, I want to apply the class "blog" to the  if the viewer is at domain.com/blog OR domain.com/blog/post-1 so on and so forth BUT apply the class "pics" if they're viewing domain.com/pics or domain.com/pics/gallery-1 etc etc.

I found something that could be modified to serve my needs using javascript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373016/apply-css-class-to-element-based-on-a-keyword-in-the-url-with-jquery)
but I figured seeing as I'm using PHP already, it'd make more sense to keep this sort of thing server side.

As I say, I'm new to PHP. I've experimented with some regular expressions, but to no avail.

EDIT: Sorry not to be more specific in my first post, I am using wordpress as my CMS - this is my first stackoverflow post, I trust you can forgive me :)

Comment: If you have found something which does the job providing you modify the code, it doesn't really matter if your using both server/client sided scripting. Do what is easiest and gets the job done

Comment: There is not really a need for regular expressions. I don't have the time to put a full answer together. But use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and possibly [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to figure out the current page and then use [the DOM module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to find the `<h1>`-tags and apply the class. If you are writing the file yourself there is not even a need to search for the `<h1>`-tags. (see popnoodles's answer)

Comment: We may need more information about how your pages are generated. Typically, you'd just output the class you want as your draw your page.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how your site is currently built? Are you using a CMS like Wordpress that you're trying to modify, or did you build your own?

Comment: I have updated the question as per your requests. I take your point @DarylGill but as I'm still new to the world of server side, I'm quite excited to learn new techniques for doing what I've traditionally relied on javascript for, regardless of the gain in efficiency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up crafting. Credit to @m.buettner for pointing me towards explode().

```
<h1 id="title-text" class="
            <?php #returns the category as a class
                $url = array();
                $url = explode('/', get_permalink());
                echo $url[3];
            ?>
            mono in-case-404">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">SITE</a>
        </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0,5)=='/pics') {
    $h1class='someclass';
}
```

The it depends on how you're putting the class in the tag, might be like this

```
?><h1 class="<?php echo $h1class; ?>">...
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting a class in based on the page, I would suggest having seperate CSS files for home.css, blog.css, whateverelse.css. Of course, these would be in addition to some sort of default.css or site.css or whatever that would contain the styles used across the site.

You can then build a function/method to create the CSS calls in the HTML header. I usually have a "Page" object that builds the actual HTML page, and a "get_css" method that spits out the CSS calls.

It's hard to get more specific without knowing how you currently build pages.